# Even or odd program with fixed number of user's attempts to enter input

Tags: python, exception, input, while-loop

I am writing a script that:

1. Asks the user to enter a number.
2. Detects errors of type 'ValueError'. The user has only 5 attempts to enter correct input.
3. If the user types in zero, the script stops execution with the message 'All done'.
4. If the user enters a positive integer, the script tells if the number is even or odd. It continues asking the user to type in another number; 10 times in total.

Here is my attempt.

```
attempt = 0
max_attempts = 5
i = 0
i_max = 10

while attempt < max_attempts:
    attempt += 1
    try:
        while i < i_max:
            i += 1
            number = int(input('Please type in a positive integer; 0 to quite: '))
            if number == 0:
                print('All done!')
                break
            if number <0:
                print('Please type in a positive number.')
            if number%2 == 0:
                print("The number",number, "is even.")
            else:
                print("The number",number, "is odd.")
            print('Only', i_max-i, 'numbers left.')
    except ValueError:
        print('Wrong input, ', max_attempts - attempt, 'attempts left')
if attempt == max_attempts: # You tried too many times
    print('Sorry, too many attempts!')
```

If the user enters 0 the script does not cease as desired.
If the user enters correct input the final string 'Sorry, too many attempts!' is printed which is not desired in this case.
How I can solve these issues? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much in advance. I apologize if I am missing something rather elementary.

Comment: if number == 0 your internal while loop only breaks but that too again run by external while loop unless you completed all the attempts.

Comment: just add `attempt = 6`  inside  ` if number == 0:` it breaks your external while loop when the user gives 0

Comment: @Ramesh Thanks for the comments. I cannot understand the last one though.

Comment: if attempt = 6, then your first while loop will not continue because attempt will be > max_attempts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add attempt = 6 inside the if condition (if number == 0)

```
attempt = 0
max_attempts = 5
i = 0
i_max = 10

while attempt < max_attempts:
    attempt += 1
    try:
        while i < i_max:
            i += 1
            number = int(input('Please type in a positive integer; 0 to quite: '))
            if number == 0:
                print('All done!')
                attempt = 6
                break
            if number < 0:
                print('Please type in a positive number.')
            if number % 2 == 0:
                print("The number", number, "is even.")
            else:
                print("The number", number, "is odd.")
            print('Only', i_max - i, 'numbers left.')
    except ValueError:
        print('Wrong input, ', max_attempts - attempt, 'attempts left')
if attempt == max_attempts:  # You tried too many times
    print('Sorry, too many attempts!')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `for` loop to control the total number of repeats the user is allowed, then a separate `failure` variable to count the number of times they enter something invalid:

```py
max_success = 10
max_failures = 5

failure = 0
for attempt in range(max_success):
    user_input = input(f' {attempt +1}/{max_success} - Ener a positive integer or 0 to quit: ')
    if user_input == '0':
        print(' Quit')
        break
    try:
        user_input = int(user_input)
        if user_input % 2 == 0:
            print(' Even number')
        else:
            print(' Odd number')
    except ValueError:
        failure += 1
        print(f' Not a number (failure {failure} of {max_failures})')
        if failure >= max_failures:
            break
```

Here's an example output if they submit 5 invalid entries:

```text
 1/10 - Ener a positive integer or 0 to quit: 5
 Odd number
 2/10 - Ener a positive integer or 0 to quit: a
 Not a number (failure 1 of 5)
 3/10 - Ener a positive integer or 0 to quit: b
 Not a number (failure 2 of 5)
 4/10 - Ener a positive integer or 0 to quit: c
 Not a number (failure 3 of 5)
 5/10 - Ener a positive integer or 0 to quit: d
 Not a number (failure 4 of 5)
 6/10 - Ener a positive integer or 0 to quit: e
 Not a number (failure 5 of 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

If the user enters 0, then you break the current while loop. However, this while loop is in another while loop. You can add a variable "is_finish". If the user enters 0, set this new variable to True. In the first while loop condition, add "is_finish == False".

Hope this help you !